# calculating height of irregular pentagon with all angles known and 3 sides known

Tags: geometry

I have the shape in the picture below. 
I have 3 known sides A,B,C and all 5 interior angles known

Is there a formula to calculate D,E,F?
Or aren't there enough datapoints?

[image: irregular polygon picture]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What relationships between $D,E,F$ can you deduce based upon your diagram? (There is in fact enough data.)

Comment: There is certainly enough information to draw it to scale so there must enough information to calculate the height in this case but if had not been given A and C but the other two sides instead then in this case there would have been infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Name the points at 145 and 135 degrees as  P and Q. P and Q are given or fixed. Take P as origin.Find equations of line through P at given inclination. Likewise also find at Q. Find point of intersection of these two lines